# Why is the short Vietnamese piece "Learning Late Letters" called a "poem"?

Tags: poetry, terminology, vietnamese-language, nguyen-hoang-quyen

["Learning Late Letters"](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/september-2020-poetry-contest-learning-late-letters-nguyen-hoang-guyen), originally written in Vietnamese by Nguyễn Hoàng Quyên, was one of the winners of the 2020 Words Without Borders [Academy of Americans Poets Poems in Translation Contest](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/poetry-contest-winners-2020-words-without-bordersacademy-of-american-poets). But, looking at the text of this short piece of literature, it doesn't fit with what I (having read mostly English poetry) would think of as a "poem". Rhyme and rhythm could be lost in translation, of course, but there are no *lines* in this piece! My instinct would be to call it short prose instead, but then I know nothing about Vietnamese poetry and its norms.

What defines "poetry" in Vietnamese literature, or why is this particular work called a poem?